# BLE on ESP32 packet Errorchecking

Tags: error-handling, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, packet-loss

when transmit data from esp32 to an esp32,does the BLE's libary contain errorchecking? AKA resending packets? uses Ack-Naks? error correction also?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is error checking.
 You can check if a write was successful.

A Ble packet consist of:

- Preamble: RF synchronization sequence.
- Access address: 32 bits, advertising or data access addresses (it is 
  used to identify the communication).
- Header: its content depends on the packet type (advertising or data
  packet).
- Length: Length of the data payload(When encryption is used, the
  message integrity code (MIC) at the end of the packet is 4 bytes, so 
  this leads to 251 bytes as actual maximum available payload size.
- Checksum: CRC.

  There is no error correction or resending of packets, unless you implement it yourself.
  So,if a write was not successful you can resend a packet.